# Display a PDF with access to its inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, pdf, amazon-s3

I have a page in which I want to display a pdf that the user has uploaded (stored on S3), and be able to access the HTML of the PDF, so the user can highlight words and sentences, change some of the words of the pdf by modifying the HTML. I imagine that if I get access to the pdf's HTML, I can easily code these features in with JavaScript. 
I already tried displaying the pdf with `<iframe>` but it seems like the inner HTML of the pdf document is hidden (although you are able to select the text on it, which baffles me).

Have you guys any idea how to approach this?

Thanks a lots

*Btw I'm developing the site with Ruby on Rails if that somehow helps or opens possibilities*

Comment: It's hidden using a [Shadow DOM tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)

Comment: @hedgie Is there any way of accessing the elements in there?

Comment: Only if you could get a reference to the shadow root. This is an interesting read: https://blog.revillweb.com/open-vs-closed-shadow-dom-9f3d7427d1af

Comment: What do you mean by the inner HTML of the pdf document? PDF files don't contain HTML. If you are displaying the PDF using some PDF to HTML5 viewer, your users won't be editing the PDF, you'd need to capture the html edits then apply them to the PDF using some other library.